# android studio/eclipse emulator showing only part of screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Since the last upgrade of packages, the Android Studio/Eclipse emulator shows only a fraction of the screen.

[image]

How can I view the whole screen again?

To re-install Eclipse does not help.

Comment: Better switch to [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) to get rid of all troubles.

Comment: don't select answer without any explanation.Since this is a bounty question so it should deserve a good answer please dont do this from next time

Comment: Please explain what you mean. 
My question was really important for me. I could hardly work with Eclipse any more. 
Since the last package upgrade in Eclipse, I could not create a decent vritual device. Even using these (Eclipse created) virtual devices in Android Studio was not correct. 
Then I created a new virtual device in Android Studio and that sovled my bounty. Of course I know that I have to migrate to Android STudio. That is what I did last weekend. 
I answered my own question because so far this seems to be the only way to solve the problem making a good virtual device for me.

Comment: no problem if only objective was to solve the problem not investigating why that was there then its ok .

Comment: Thank you. It "helped" me to go to Android Studio faster. End good ... all good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First this seemed the solution: creating a new virtual device in Android Studio solved the problem.

The same problem re-appeared today in Android Studio. I found the definite and simple soluion. You can set it explicitly in the Android Studio AVD manager.

How? Start Android Studio, menubar "Tools" > "Android" > "AVD manager". Then set the startup size and orientation. I changed it from "Auto" to the one below:

[image]

Comment: So far, this is the only solution that solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Two different settings influence the display size of a virtual device. The actual hardware display size of the specific hardware being emulated (Nexus One, Nexus S, ...) and the scaling factor that the emulator applies when rendering that display onto your computer screen. Both are properties of the virtual android device, so reinstalling Eclipse will not change them, but you can edit them in the Android Virtual Device Manager or on launching your emulator.

If you run your emulator from the command line, the third paragraph of the [command line help page](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) describes how to change both settings.

If you run your emulator from Eclipse, you may want to look at the launch configuration that you use for debugging your application. At the very bottom you can give the scaling factor and other properties as additional command line arguments. Make sure this is not set.

If nothing worked until here, just create a new virtual device for your emulator from the Eclipse toolbar.

Comment: 1 - The scale factor does not help. It changes the overall size. It does not change the scale of the screen itself.
2 - I created new virtual devices, but only a fraction of the screen is shown. I would like to see the complete screen. 
3 - How can I change the launch configuration ... so the whole screen is shown?

Comment: Thanking you for pointing me in the right direction. 
I solved it when I saw that even in Android studio the virtual devices were not responding well. So, I created a new virtual device in Android Studio and it worked.